# Add /dev/sda8 to bootloader

Tags: 11.10, bootloader

I've set up another ubuntu on my computer.

So when I start-up my computer I can select from windows 7 or ubuntu 11.10.

**But** I've installed ubuntu 11.10 two times and I can't start the one which is on `/dev/sda8`

So how can I add my second ubuntu 11.10 to the bootloader?

Comment: Note that I stopped using windows and ubuntu ages ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following in a terminal to update your bootloader:

`sudo update-grub`

You'll see something like this:

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-14-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-14-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-12-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-12-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2
Found Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on /dev/sda3
```

Look for `/dev/sda8` in there, if its not there then you have another problem.

If `/dev/sda8` shows up, reboot your computer and look at the bootloader (purple screen) before Ubuntu starts to boot. At that point, just look around - I suspect that you'll find 11.10 down at the bottom of that menu.